# jQuery Find() not working in Firefox or IE

Tags: javascript

I'd like to change the attribute of a Google Calendar select element.

The code I'm trying works in WebKit browsers, but not in FF or IE.

Here's what I have:

```
$jqry('iframe').contents().find('.calendar-nav').attr('style','display: table; background: blue');
```

I think it's getting stuck on the find() function. Is my iframe being treated as ajax? Is the issue being caused by mime/content type? Please help with a code example if possible.

Many thanks!

Comment: You say that DOES work in some browsers?? What you're attempting is known as Cross-site Scripting (XSS for short). It's a bad thing, and most browsers will not allow you to mess with the contents of an iframe.

Comment: If the `<iframe>` contains content from the same domain as the parent page, there's no problem.

Comment: @Pointy True, but the OP is most likely using an iframe pointing to Google, as that's the standard way of embedding a Google Calendar.

Comment: Ah duhh, yes @RyanP now I see that. You're probably right.

Comment: I really don't think that is XSS by definition. Although I wouldn't wager on it because I'm no security expert. I'm still hoping to get a work around though..  :[

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Chrome/Firefox:

```
xml.children[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML
```

IE8+/Safari:

```
xml.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].textContent
```

IE8:

```
xml.documentElement.childNodes[1].text;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked for me. It seems Firefox and IE didn't like the vagueness of having only a tag selector: `$('iframe')`. As soon as I added a class it worked: `$('.myiframe')`. I'm guessing an ID would work just the same: `$('#myiframe')`. I was only using the tag selector because I didn't want to modify the plugin I was using, and it was the only iframe on the page -- oh well. Thanks to those who provided input.